# Two Serializer CreateAPIView - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have create a view which is bellow. Similar i have to create `CreateAPIView`. In the follwing `EmployeeAddView` i have took two `forms` and added data according. But i am not getting how to do it in REST API.

```
@login_required
def EmployeeAddView(request):

    # Tab Opts Checking
    if request.user.userprofile.user_company.company_tab_opts:
            return redirect('admin_employee')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        random_password = User.objects.make_random_password() # generate password here 
        ur_form = EmployeeRegisterForm(request.POST, pwd=random_password)
        pr_form = EmployeeProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user_company=request.user.userprofile.user_company.id)

        user_role = ACLRoles.objects.get(id=4)

        if ur_form.is_valid() and pr_form.is_valid():

            new_user = ur_form.save(commit=False)            
            new_user.username = new_user.email
            new_user.set_password(random_password)
            new_user.save()

            profile =  pr_form.save(commit=False)
            if profile.user_id is None:
                profile.user_id = new_user.id
                profile.user_role_id = user_role.id
                profile.user_company_id = request.user.userprofile.user_company.id
            profile.save()

            for group in request.POST.getlist('user_groups'): # For many to many field
                profile.user_groups.add(group)

            email= ur_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(request, 'Employee Added - %s!' % email)
            return redirect('admin_employee')

    else:
        ur_form = EmployeeRegisterForm(use_required_attribute=False)
        pr_form = EmployeeProfileForm(user_company=request.user.userprofile.user_company.id, use_required_attribute=False)

    return render(request, 'employee/employee_form.html', {'ur_form': ur_form, 'pr_form': pr_form})
```

This is my try but i am not getting how to do it
API-views.py

```
class EmployeeAddAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeRegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = [UserIsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(
            userprofile__user_company = self.request.auth.application.company,
      )
```

API-Serializer.py

```
class EmployeeProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [  'user_employee_id',
                    'user_phone', 
                    'user_payroll_id',
                    'user_hire_date',
                    'user_pay_rate',
                    'user_salaried',
                    'user_excempt',
                    'user_groups',
                    'user_state',
                    'user_city',
                    'user_zipcode', 
                    'user_status',
        ]

class EmployeeRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userprofile = EmployeeProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name', 'email', 'userprofile']
```

How should i do it.

I did something like this

```
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status

    class EmployeeAddAPIView(APIView):

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwrgs):

            serializer1 = EmployeeRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer2 = EmployeeProfileSerializer(data=request.data)

            user_role = ACLRoles.objects.get(id=4)

            if serializer1.is_valid():
                print('inside')
                new_user = serializer1.save(commit=False)            
                new_user.username = new_user.email
                new_user.set_password(random_password)
                new_user.save()

                profile =  serializer2.save(commit=False)
                if profile.user_id is None:
                    profile.user_id = new_user.id
                    profile.user_role_id = user_role.id
                    profile.user_company_id = self.request.auth.application.company
                profile.save()


                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            print('outside', serializer1)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Can you show full error log

Comment: Sorry but i remove that code - i did with some other code it is not validating. It is not coming inside `if serializer1.is_valid() and serializer2.is_valid():`

Comment: try to print errors like this --> print(serializer1.errors)

Comment: AssertionError: 'commit' is not a valid keyword argument to the 'save()' method. If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead. You can also pass additional keyword arguments to 'save()' if you need to set extra attributes on the saved model instance. For example: 'serializer.save(owner=request.user)'.'

Comment: drf serializer don't act like django forms

Comment: So how should i do it.

Comment: please go through docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 2 serializer same as you add 2 forms

in serailizer.py

```
class Model1SerailizerOne(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    # code

class Model2SerailizerTwo(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    # code
```

in api.py

```
class APICreateView(APIView):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwrgs):

      serializer1 = Model1SerailizerOne(data=request.data)
      serializer2 = Model2SerailizerTwo(data=request.data)

      if serializer1.is_valid() and serializer2.is_valid():

           # save code
         return ....
```

hope it helps

This will work -

```
class EmployeeAddAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [UserIsAuthenticated]
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwrgs):

        serializer1 = EmployeeRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer2 = EmployeeProfileSerializer(data=request.data)

        user_role = ACLRoles.objects.get(id=4)

        if serializer1.is_valid():

            print(serializer1.validated_data['email'])
            user = serializer1.save(
                username = serializer1.validated_data['email'],
            )

            random_password = User.objects.make_random_password()
            obj = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user.id)
            obj.set_password(random_password)
            obj.save()

            print(serializer1.errors)

            if serializer2.is_valid():
                serializer2.save(
                    user_id = user.id,
                    user_company_id = self.request.auth.application.company.id,
                    user_role_id = user_role.id
                )

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: I did something like this see in the question last section it is giving error